# Energy in active noise cancellation

Tags: noise, phase-shift

In an active noise cancellation system, to what form of energy is noise converted and how is the energy produced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Active noise cancellation works by generating a sound with 180 degree phase shift from the original sound. It's effectively an interference effect.

Like any interference effect, it doesn't produce cancellation everywhere. If the phase shift is 180 degrees at one location, it will be 0 degrees at some other location, resulting in a greater sound intensity there. So it doesn't convert the energy to another form, it just moves sound energy from one location to another.

Answer (score 0):

The active noise cancellation is essentially a generation of a sound wave which will produce  a [destructive interference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interference_(wave_propagation)) with the incoming wave at the vicinity of your ears. So the energy is not going to anywhere, there are still two acoustic waves traveling in different directions and carrying their energies.

Comment: Am I right to assume that the acoustic pressure will be around twice the initial pressure alone?

Comment: No. It will be the case of constructive interference. In the destructive one the waves will be in the opposite phase, so the high pressure will cancel out with the low pressure of the second wave and vice versa.

Comment: Glad to see my assumption was wrong as I was reluctant to test such systems. What about the physiological effect of energy on the other hand (I guess on the energy stand point it doubles, right)?

Comment: There is no energy in the vicinity of the cancellation point. It is just "transferred" elsewhere in the space, where the sum of the waves is non-zero.